# flat json to structured mapping

Tags: json, dataweave

How do I map the following in dataweave 2.0 .. I am able to split the first element .. I need to form my list based of the first element in my input and parse out the remaining under appropriate indexes. for e.g. when there is a 5th value something.pem, there will be subsequent values for it and the output array need to be populated

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload[0] splitBy  (/\s/)
map (certs, index) ->  {
 certsname: certs,
 validfrome: (payload filter ($$<=4)) [index+1],
 validto: (payload filter ($$<=4)) [index+2],
 issuer: (payload filter ($$<=4)) [index+3], 
 subject: (payload filter ($$<=5)) [index+4]
}
```

Input

```
[
  "auth0.pem maximo.cer synovos.pem veevavault.pem",
  "notBefore=Apr 30 00:00:00 2020 GMT",
  "notAfter=May 30 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
  "issuer= /C=US/O=Amazon/OU=Server CA 1B/CN=Amazon",
  "subject= /CN=auth0.com",
  "notBefore=Feb  5 18:02:21 2020 GMT",
  "notAfter=Apr  5 18:44:22 2021 GMT",
  "issuer= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./OU=http://certs.starfieldtech.com/repository//CN=Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2",
  "subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.corp.amazon.com",
  "notBefore=Aug  1 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
  "notAfter=Aug 15 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
  "issuer= /C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscloud.net) (t)",
  "subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.synovos.com",
  "notBefore=Jan 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT",
  "notAfter=Jan 27 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
  "issuer= /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA",
  "subject= /C=US/ST=California/L=Pleasanton/O=Veeva Systems, Inc./OU=Vault/CN=*.veevavault.com"
]
```

to an Output

```
[
  {
    "certsname": "auth0.pem",
    "validfrome": "notBefore=Apr 30 00:00:00 2020 GMT",
    "validto": "notAfter=May 30 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": "issuer= /C=US/O=Amazon/OU=Server CA 1B/CN=Amazon",
    "subject": "subject= /CN=auth0.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "maximo.cer",
    "validfrom": "notBefore=Feb  5 18:02:21 2020 GMT",
    "validto": "Apr  5 18:44:22 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": "/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./OU=http://certs.starfieldtech.com/repository//CN=Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2\"",
    "subject": "subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.corp.amazon.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "synovos.pem",
    "validfrom": "notBefore=Aug  1 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
    "validto": "notAfter=Aug 15 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
    "issuer": "issuer= /C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscloud.net) (t)",
    "subject": "subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.synovos.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "veevavault.pem",
    "validfrom": "notBefore=Jan 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT",
    "validto": "notAfter=Jan 27 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": "issuer= /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA",
    "subject": "subject= /C=US/ST=California/L=Pleasanton/O=Veeva Systems, Inc./OU=Vault/CN=*.veevavault.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can optimize this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var validFrom = ((payload map {
    (($$): $) if($ contains("notBefore"))
}) - ({}))
var validTo = ((payload map {
    (($$): $) if($ contains("notAfter"))
}) - ({}))
var issuer = ((payload map {
    (($$): $) if($ contains("issuer"))
}) - ({}))
var subject = ((payload map {
    (($$): $) if($ contains("subject"))
}) - ({}))
---

payload[0] splitBy  (/\s/) map {
 certsname: $,
 validfrom: validFrom[$$][0],
 validto: validTo[($$)][0],
 issuer: issuer[$$][0],
 subject: subject[$$][0]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The input array is a pretty bad structure. I advice to make it more structured instead. If you can't change it, then below is the script I made to get the expected output.

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Strings
var certs=payload[0] splitBy   (/\s/)
var attributes=payload[1 to sizeOf(payload)-1]
var certAttributes=attributes divideBy 4 // assume there are exactly 4 attributes per certificate
fun splitAttribute(a)={ (substringBefore(a,'=')): substringAfter (a, '=')}
fun attributesToObject(x)=x reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item)
---
certAttributes map (
    {certsname: certs[$$]} ++ attributesToObject( $ map splitAttribute($))
)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "certsname": "auth0.pem",
    "notBefore": "Apr 30 00:00:00 2020 GMT",
    "notAfter": "May 30 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": " /C=US/O=Amazon/OU=Server CA 1B/CN=Amazon",
    "subject": " /CN=auth0.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "maximo.cer",
    "notBefore": "Feb  5 18:02:21 2020 GMT",
    "notAfter": "Apr  5 18:44:22 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": " /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./OU=http://certs.starfieldtech.com/repository//CN=Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2",
    "subject": " /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.corp.amazon.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "synovos.pem",
    "notBefore": "Aug  1 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
    "notAfter": "Aug 15 17:57:31 2020 GMT",
    "issuer": " /C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscloud.net) (t)",
    "subject": " /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.synovos.com"
  },
  {
    "certsname": "veevavault.pem",
    "notBefore": "Jan 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT",
    "notAfter": "Jan 27 12:00:00 2021 GMT",
    "issuer": " /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA",
    "subject": " /C=US/ST=California/L=Pleasanton/O=Veeva Systems, Inc./OU=Vault/CN=*.veevavault.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun getValue(key) = payload[?($ contains key)]
---
payload[0] splitBy  (" ") map {
  certsname: $,
  validfrom: getValue("notBefore")[($$)],
  validto: getValue("notAfter")[($$)],
  issuer: getValue("issuer")[($$)],
  subject: getValue("subject")[($$)]
}
```